# Firebase SDK multiple projects in one apk

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I am trying to initialize the FirebaseApp, only by using the FirebaseOptions builder, like this(I use only applicationId and ApiKey, since I only want the analytics for start):

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setApplicationId(applicationID) // Required for Analytics.
.setApiKey(apiKey) // Required for Auth.
.build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options);
```

I do not have a google-services.json file in my project, I have removed the FirebaseInitProvider, like this, in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
   android:exported="false"
   tools:node="remove"/>
```

I would like to have the application id sent from my server, since I want more than one projects, and I don't really care if I lose some event during the initialization of the app.
When starting the application, while trying to View events in the Android Studio debug log, like this:

`adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE`

`adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE`

`adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC`

I get: `Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.`

I do not want to use google_app_id in a `strings.xml` static file since I want more than one projects. However I tried having all the app ids in an XML file and trying to change them using reflection before the FirebaseApp.initializeApp, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you even create multiple Firebase projects that each define a configuration for an app with the same package name? What about having a different package name for each app? I'm trying to understand *why* you would need this.

Answer (score 1):

the **default** `FirebaseApp` initialization looks alike this (this is being used when passing no name):

```
FirebaseApp fb = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "[DEFAULT]");
```

> The `FirebaseOptions` values used by the default app instance **are read from string resources**.

but ...one can instead assign custom names, in order **not** to read from string resources:

```
FirebaseApp fb01 = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "primary");
FirebaseDatabase db01 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(fb01);

FirebaseApp fb02 = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, "secondary");
FirebaseDatabase db02 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(fb02);
```

found this [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html), which is the credible source requested.

also the documentation for [FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions,%20java.lang.String)) generally explains it.

Comment: why the down-vote without leaving an explanation? this is not documented, but fact.

Comment: OP is interested in providing a Firebase configuration dynamically at runtime. Having a pre-bundled string resource in the APK doesn't fit the description.

Comment: I agree that that's the typical use case, but for some reason OP has need to provide the configuration and initialize Firebase at runtime, quote: `I would like to have the application id sent from my server` (that's the Firebase App ID).

Comment: @EugenPechanec improved my answer, so that no string resource are required... alike this is appears rather possible, than with the default initialization, which depends on string resources with unique names.

Comment: The thing is that in order to use FirebaseAnalytics only the "[DEFAULT]" project is taken into consideration. Furthermore, even when I try to set the "[DEFAULT]" project, using a custom FirebaseOptions, it doesn't work, but I get the "Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled" message I mentioned above

Comment: @paularius with `"[DEFAULT]"` you will certainly get the error, because it will depend on string resources. there's only `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);` - that one cannot pass the instance of `FirebaseApp` is the culprit (unless it would extend `Context`). user properties to filter by might be the only option - or open a support ticket with a feature request.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I just want to have different projects, instead of just filtering user properties...I have already opened an issue in the github project, but maybe someone has achieved something like the thing I want to.

Comment: @paularius the documentation is pretty clear about it, what is possible and what isn't... besides, for analytics it is far more common to have campaign ids, than to use several trackers.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I don't think that it is that clear, since they have implemented FirebaseOptions and FirebaseApp.initialiazeApp, that works fine with the other projects except for the FirebaseAnalytics. Furthermore, I was able to implement this scenario in iOS application, using only keys from server. Thanks for your research, anyway!

Comment: Fabric Answers might be an alternative.